# Can I add Models Dynamically in XNA

Tags: xna, models, user-generated-content

i want to add Models (FBX) to My XNA Game without adding them to the "Game Content Project" , so the user could choose his own model , how could i implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to add Models (FBX) to My XNA Game without adding them to the "Game Content Project" , so the user could choose his own model , how could i implement this ?

I'm assuming that the model is created by the user or the third party. If so take a look at this [codeplex project](http://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/). It can run the content compiler at run-time should be pretty easy to replace the GUI with however you want the user to pick their model.

Edit: Codeplex appears to be down but hopefully it'll be back up soon

Answer (score 1):

Are you targeting Xbox or Windows for this project?

If you're targeting Windows, then you can just use the existing content pipeline classes and call them manually to import and process models into your game.  When you get to deployment though, I think you'll have to ensure that the pipeline dlls are included (just set Copy Local to true in the reference properties).  Not sure if they're part of the XNA redistributable or not.

Comment: i tried that before (for another purpose) , the XNA redistributable doesn't include the pipeline dlls